# Intel (windows) c++ compiler and changing its library implementation to gcc. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, c++11, intel

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but here goes

From a [page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-windows-general-compatibility-with-other-products) on the Intel website, it states:

> The Intel C++ Compiler for Windows **uses the Microsoft Visual C++ header files, libraries and linker**. Microsoft controls the header files that define the namespace. Contact Microsoft's technical support in reference to Microsoft's conformance to the C++ standard on this issue... [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-windows-general-compatibility-with-other-products)

Is there a guide by Intel (or otherwise) to change the libraries from the ones governed by **visual studio** to ones provided by **gcc** (Also on my windows machine). the reason I want to do this is to make use of some of the new C++11 features that are not supported in versions of visual studio (as is generally the case)

If this is not possible because my current knowledge of the above is not correct, can somebody explain to me why not.

Thanks.

Comment: gcc doesn't provide libraries, or rather it doesn't provide very many. Do you mean [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)? (gcc on Windows, at least in the MinGW implementation, typically uses Microsoft's libraries; in general, it usually uses whatever libraries are available on the system.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry my terminology on some specifics is minimal. I think library is the wrong term, and I don't mean the C libraries. I'm more concerned with the Standard Template Library (STL) header files. Given the above quote from the Intel page *...uses the Microsoft Visual C++ header files, libraries and linker*, I was thinking if there was a way to instead use GCC *header files, libraries and linker*. (In this way actually the Intel compiler will very much be the same as on Linux systems I believe if we are just talking about *header files, libraries and linker*)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a practical possibility.

The intel compiler (icl) will do nothing but moan if it cannot find VC++ binaries on the `PATH`, so you know it needs the VC++ toolchain at least.

Then to see what you are up against, as far as using the gcc headers is concerned, you would do the following:

- Make icl suppress its own predefined macros.
- Make it use gcc's predefined macros.
- Make it suppress its standard include search.
- Make it use gcc's standard include search.

None of this is hard, and when you have done it all and attempted to build your `HelloWorld.cpp`, the errors
will show you that the gcc headers are replete with builtin keywords of the gcc compiler that are 
unknown to icl: `__builtin_va_list`, `__attribute__`, `__cdecl__`, `__nothrow__` and so on.

You might attempt to successfully delete or redefine all of these by way of preprocessor macros. 
Or you might give up, and I would urge the latter.